# Compute mean for multi group of panda dataframe rows

Tags: pandas

From a panda dataframe with theses columns:

```
DAT_MESURE         datetime64[ns]
MES_TEMPERATURE            object
```

and values:

[image]

I want to compute the mean temperature value for a group of hours and get a new df.
For example, I want to create a new df with DAT_MESURE rounded to lowest hour and a mean for 4 values of the hour.

I want to get:

```
DAT_MESURE MES_TEMPERATURES
2020-08-01 00:00:00 21,xx
2020-08-01 01:00:00 22,xx
```

How to code it in python panda please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['MES_TEMPERATURE'] = df['MES_TEMPERATURE'].str.replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float)

df1 = df.resample('H', on='DAT_MESURE')['MES_TEMPERATURE'].mean()
```

Or:

```
df2 = df.groupby(df['DAT_MESURE'].dt.floor('H'))['MES_TEMPERATURE'].mean()
```

If need round:

```
df3 = df.groupby(df['DAT_MESURE'].dt.round('H'))['MES_TEMPERATURE'].mean()
```